# Design Data Structures For Somp Operation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, tree

I ran into a challenging problem recently.

Suppose n integer between 1 and SQRT(n) is given. (maybe repeated number and not different between them) we want to design an structure that use low memory do Insert / Delete / Search operation.

How we design O(1) for all operation and memory SQRT(n)?

any idea or hint is so nice !

200000!!!!  thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your data structure - as you add more an more elements, n increases. Does that mean that the upper bound on the number of elements also increases?

Comment: Dear @templatetypedef, in fact i want to design efficient data structure that these operation has complexity of O(1) and memory SQRT(n).

Comment: Is n known in advance?

Comment: Dear @templatetypedef, just we know n number between 1 and SQRT(n) is given.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the insert and delete operations - are all n values known in advance? Can more elements be added later? Can elements be deleted later?

Comment: Dear @templatetypedef, you are right, but it's not given. in which condition we have O(1) on these operation and memory = SQRT(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice and short article about counting sort at http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/sorting/countingsort and here is the code

```
public void countingsort(int[] input, int k) {
    // create buckets
    int counter[] = new int[k + 1];
    // fill buckets
    for (int i : input) {
      counter[i]++;
    }
    // sort array
    int ndx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
      while (0 < counter[i]) {
        input[ndx++] = i;
        counter[i]--;
      }
    }
  }
```

Notice that `k` here is your `SQRT(n)`.

In particular you want **O(1) delete, insert, and search**

to delete a number x from the numbers you simply do

```
public boolean delete(int x){
   if (0< counter[x]){
     counter[x]--;
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

to insert a number x into the numbers you do

```
public void insert(int x){ counter[x]++;}
```

to search you do

```
public boolean contains(int x){return 0< counter[x];}
```

Also you can easily find the frequency of a particular number with

```
public int frequency(int x){return counter[x];}
```

If you need more help let me know.

Comment: Dear Labapen, How i prove the memory is SQRT(N)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by improve. The memory is already `SQRT(N)` by virtue that your numbers range from 0 to SQRT(N). See where I tell you that `k` is equal to `SQRT(N)`. Your array is of size `k+1` which is `O(sgrt(n))`. So it already is.

Answer (score 0):

While pondering what to keep about n naturals up to SQRT(n), we read up on [counting_sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) and borrow the main idea.

Comment: would you please add detail here? and say main idea?